# Stepper Motor Hat v0.1 - pre-soldered version

Tags: servo, hat

I am pretty new and have installed the referenced HAT. I followed the instructions, but it is not detected.

I have power and a green LED on the board and when I turn it on and off the servos jump a bit, so it seems like it is physically OK. I have enabled I2C, but it doesn't show up.

I am using RPi 3 B+ with the latest Raspbian install. I am pretty new, so let me know what other info I need to provide here. I see this is a common topic and it usually seems to be a power issue, but I am pretty sure that is not my issue.

[image]

[image]

From first image above, 5v @ two blue screws (upper left). 
Second image is my photo, one servo on 0 & and one on 1 (PMW/Servo pins).

Using latest version of Raspian, did: 
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-smbus
$ sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools

Then enabled i2c in rasp-config and shut down Pi.

Installed HAT (just drops on top and pushed down on 2x20 pins), powered HAT, powered and booted Pi.

I then installed the Python tools that came with the unit from wget sourceforge.net/projects/u-geek/files/HATs/Raspi_MotorHAT/Ra spi_MotorHAT.tar but that doesn't seem to impact the config or allow the HAT to show up when I use sudo i2cdetect -y 1.

Comment: You should include a diagram or picture of your wiring and the code you are using.

Comment: please add all of the information in your comment into the original question .... use the edit button ..... when the information is added to the question, then delete the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get any answers, so I tried the random things method.  It seems to work now and I have the addresses needed for the servos from ic2detect.

Solution:  you MUST boot up the Pi with the HAT installed but the power OFF.  Then put the power to the HAT and the Pi seems to suddenly recognize the device.  Not sure why at all, so I can't provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.